# why $N = 1 / \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences

Here is the part of the text I am asking about:

> [image]

I am wondering, why in the proof that the sequence $x_m$ is Cauchy the writer used that $N = 1/ \epsilon,$ could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The area of the triangle pictured in the second figure is $\frac12\left\lvert\frac1m - \frac1n\right\rvert \le \frac12\left(\frac1m + \frac1n\right)$ (by triangle inequality). Thus, if you pick both $m$ and $n$ greater than $\frac 1\varepsilon$, you will have the area is $< \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

If you go far enough out in the sequence that $m, n \geq N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, then you have
$$
\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon, 
$$
and the area of that triangle is less than
$$
\frac{1}{2m}, 
$$
assuming WLOG that $m < n$ (if not just swap the roles).

Does this help you understand the proof?

Comment: Why $N > 1/ \epsilon$? are you using the Archimedian property for 1 and $\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, the fact that such a value of $N \in \mathbb{N}$ exists is due to the Archimedean property.